# Add new line (and bullet points) in Django forms label?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a form:

```
class FormFood(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = [ (1,'Yes'), (2, 'No')]
    response = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,
              label="Would you like some pasta, bread or rice?", choices=CHOICES)
```

It appears like this in my browser:

[image]

## The problem

I would like 'pasta', 'bread' and 'rice' to appear on different lines with bullet points like this:

Would you like:

- Pasta
- Bread
- Rice

## What I've tried

Adding \n in the label text and skipping a line using 'enter'. Neither have worked.

Could somebody point me in the right direction as to how best to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with closing tag of `'<ul>'` there will be a continuous spaces if you ever need to add more labels. but with close '`</ul>'` tag all other label with different option will aligned.

```
label = 'Would you like: <ul><li>pasta</li><li>bread</li><li>rice</li></ul>'
```

Comment: I copied your line directly but I'm still getting raw html output: Would you like: <ul><li>pasta</li><li>bread</li><li>rice</li></ul> :(

Comment: try double quote label = "Would you like: <ul><li>pasta</li><li>bread</li><li>rice</li></ul>"

Comment: Thanks Ali. Unfortunately, the double quotes don't seem to affect it. Perhaps its a Django forms thing? I'm not sure

Comment: welcome Tom, but if you want to hard code this label string you can directly add this in your .html file. i have tried this its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes than double quotes and write the following-

```
label='Would you like: <ul><li>pasta</li><li>bread</li><li>rice</li></ul>'
```

Comment: In my browser this outputs the raw html/text:   Would you like: <ul><li>pasta</li><li>bread</li><li>rice</li>

Comment: just double checking that you used single quotes, and not double quotes? Also which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, I've copied and pasted your line directly :(